# Изменение матрицы в соответствии с подматрицой

Tags: c++

Работают все функции,но если менять местами строчки в подматрице,то нужно чтобы и в исходной матрице произошли изменения,не могу сообразить как делать

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class Badsize{};
class Badindex{};
class Badvalue{};
class Matrix;
Matrix operator + (const Matrix& x, const double y);
Matrix operator - (const Matrix& x, const double y);
Matrix operator * (const Matrix& x, const double y);
Matrix & operator += (const Matrix& x, const double y);
Matrix & operator -= (const Matrix& x, const double y);
Matrix & operator *= (const Matrix& x, const double y);
bool operator == (const Matrix& x, const double y);
bool operator != (const Matrix& x, const double y);
int globali=0,globalj=0;
//int i, j;
//double v = 1;
//
//search(v, i,j);
//
//Matrix::search(double value, int& i, int& j);
struct MatrixIndex {
            int firstindi, firstindj;
        };

class Matrix
{

    int kolrow,kolcol,firsteli,firstelj;

    //bool submatrix;
    private:
        Matrix(Matrix& s,int kolel,int usekolel,int kolrow);//содержит указатель на первый элемент матрицы,количество элементов в строке,
                                                              //используемое количество элементов из строки,количество строк
    public:
        double **mass;
        bool submatrix;//флажок, определяющий выделена ли была память в конструкторе=0 или используется память другого объекта=1
        Matrix(int kolrow,int kolcol);//конструктор(количество строк,количество столбцов)
        Matrix(const Matrix& m);//конструктор копий
        ~Matrix();
        Matrix sub(int i,int j,int n,int m);//подматрица
        Matrix row(int i);//строка
        Matrix col(int j);//столбец
        Matrix operator + (const Matrix& x);
        Matrix operator - (const Matrix& x);
        Matrix operator * (const Matrix& x);
        Matrix & operator = (const Matrix& x);
        Matrix & operator += (const Matrix& x);
        Matrix & operator -= (const Matrix& x);
        Matrix & operator *= (const Matrix& x);
        bool operator == (const Matrix& x);
        bool operator != (const Matrix& x);
        Matrix operator / (double y);
        Matrix operator /= (double y);
        Matrix transp ();//транспонирование
        double max();//максимум
        double min();//минимум
        MatrixIndex find(double value/*,MatrixIndex &s, int& i, int& j*/);//поиск элемента
        friend istream & operator>>(istream &is,Matrix &x);//ввод
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os,Matrix &x);//вывод
        Matrix onematrix(int n);//единичная матрица
        Matrix zeromatrix(int n);//нулевая матрица
        double operator () (const int &i,const int &j);//возвратит ссылку на элемент
        Matrix copy ();//создает копию матрицы с выделением собственной памяти
        int rows(){return kolrow;} ;//количество строк в матрице
        int cols(){return kolcol;};//количество столбцов в матрице
        //Vector operator [] (int row) { return Vector(this, row);}
};
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m):kolrow(m.kolrow),kolcol(m.kolcol),firsteli(m.firsteli),firstelj(m.firstelj),submatrix(m.submatrix)//конструктор копий
{
    if(submatrix) mass = m.mass;
    else{
        mass=new double* [kolrow+m.firsteli];
    for(int i=0;i<kolrow+m.firstelj;i++)
    {
        mass[i]= new double [kolcol+m.firstelj];
    }

        for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+m.firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+m.firstelj;j++)
            {mass[i][j]=m.mass[i][j];
    //cout<<mass[i][j]<<' '<<i<<' '<<j<<'\n';
        }
    }

}

Matrix::Matrix(Matrix& s,int kolel,int usekolel,int kolrow)//содержит указатель на первый элемент матрицы,количество элементов в строке,
{   
                                                               //используемое количество элементов из строки,количество строк
    if(s.firsteli<0||s.firstelj<0)
        throw Badindex();
    if(kolel<=0||kolrow<=0||kolel>s.kolcol-s.firstelj||kolrow>s.kolrow-s.firsteli)
        throw Badsize();
    this->firsteli=globali;
    this->firstelj=globalj;
    this->kolcol=kolel;
    this->kolrow=kolrow;
    this->mass=(s.mass);
    this->submatrix=1;
}
Matrix::Matrix(int kolrow,int kolcol)//конструктор(количество строк,количество столбцов)
{
    this->firsteli=0;
    this->firstelj=0;
    this->kolcol=kolcol;
    this->kolrow=kolrow;
    mass=new double* [kolrow];
    for(int i=0;i<kolrow;i++)
    {
        mass[i]= new double [kolcol];
    }
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
            for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
            mass[i][j]=0;
    this->submatrix=0;
}
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    if(!submatrix)//только для матриц
    {
        for (int i=firsteli;i<kolrow;i++)
            delete [] mass[i];
        delete [] mass;
    }
}
Matrix Matrix:: sub(int i,int j,int n,int m)//подматрица
{
    globali=i;
    globalj=j;
    Matrix& s(*this);
    return Matrix (s,m,m,n);
}
Matrix Matrix:: row(int i)//строка
{
    globali=i;
    globalj=firstelj;
    Matrix& s(*this);
    return Matrix (s,kolcol,kolcol,1);
}
Matrix Matrix::col(int j)//столбец
{
    globali=firsteli;
    globalj=j;
    Matrix& s(*this);
    return Matrix (s,1,1,kolrow);
}

Matrix Matrix::operator + (const Matrix& x)
{/*
    if (kolrow!=x.kolrow||kolcol!=x.kolcol)
        throw Badsize();
    Matrix s(*this);
    s.copy();

    for(int i=0;i<kolrow;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<kolcol;j++)
        {
            s.mass[i][j]+=x.mass[i][j];
        }
    return s;*/
    return copy()+=x;
}
Matrix Matrix::operator - (const Matrix& x)
{
    //if (kolrow!=x.kolrow||kolcol!=x.kolcol)
    //  throw Badsize();
    //Matrix s(*this);
    ////s=copy(Matrix(*this));
    //for(int i=0;i<kolrow;i++)
    //  for(int j=0;j<kolcol;j++)
    //  {
    //      s.mass[i][j]-=x.mass[i][j];
    //  }
    //s.flag=1;
    //return s;
    return copy()-=x;
}
Matrix Matrix::operator * (const Matrix& x)
{
    //if (kolcol!=x.kolrow)
    //  throw Badsize();
    //Matrix s(kolcol,x.kolrow);
    ////s=copy(Matrix(*this));
    //for(int i=0;i<kolrow;i++)
    //  for(int j=0;j<x.kolcol;j++)
    //      for(int k=0;k<kolcol;k++)
    //      {
    //          s.mass[i][j]+=mass[i][k]*x.mass[k][j];
    //      }
    //s.flag=1;
    //return s;
    return this->copy()*=x;
}
Matrix & Matrix::operator = (const Matrix& x)
{
    Matrix tmp(x);
    swap(kolrow,tmp.kolrow);
    swap(kolcol,tmp.kolcol);
    swap(submatrix,tmp.submatrix);
    swap(firsteli,tmp.firsteli);
    swap(firstelj,tmp.firstelj);
    swap(mass,tmp.mass);
    return *this;
}
Matrix & Matrix::operator += (const Matrix& x)
{
    if (kolrow!=x.kolrow||kolcol!=x.kolcol)
        throw Badsize();
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
        {
            mass[i][j]+=x.mass[i][j];
        }
    return *this;
}
Matrix & Matrix::operator -= (const Matrix& x)
{
    if (kolrow!=x.kolrow||kolcol!=x.kolcol)
        throw Badsize();
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
        {
            mass[i][j]-=x.mass[i][j];
        }
    return *this;
}
Matrix & Matrix::operator *= (const Matrix& x)
{
    if (kolcol!=x.kolrow)
        throw Badsize();
    Matrix s(kolcol,x.kolrow);
    //s=copy(Matrix(*this));
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
            for(int k=0;k<kolcol;k++)
            {
                s.mass[i][j]+=mass[i][k]*x.mass[k][j];
            }
    *this=s;
    return *this;
}
bool Matrix::operator == (const Matrix& x)
{
    if (kolrow==x.kolrow && kolcol==x.kolcol)
    {
        for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
                if(mass[i][j]==x.mass[i][j]);
                else return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
bool Matrix::operator != (const Matrix& x)
{
    return !(*this==x);
}
Matrix Matrix::operator / (double y)
{
    //if (y==0)
    //  throw Badvalue();
    //Matrix s(*this);
    ////s=copy(Matrix(*this));
    //for(int i=0;i<kolrow;i++)
    //  for(int j=0;j<kolcol;j++)
    //  {
    //      s.mass[i][j]=s.mass[i][j]/y;
    //  }
    //s.flag=1;
    //return s;
    return copy()/=y;
}
Matrix Matrix::operator /= (double y)
{
    if (y==0)
        throw Badvalue();
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
        {
            mass[i][j]=mass[i][j]/y;
        }
    return *this;
}
Matrix Matrix:: transp ()//транспонирование
{
    Matrix s(kolcol,kolrow);
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
        {
            s.mass[i][j]=mass[j][i];
        }
    *this=s;
    return *this;
}
double Matrix::max()//максимум
{
    double s=mass[firsteli][firstelj];
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
        {
            if(mass[i][j]>s)
                s=mass[i][j];
        }
    return s;
}
double Matrix::min()//минимум
{
    double s=mass[firsteli][firstelj];
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
        {
            if(mass[i][j]<s)
                s=mass[i][j];
        }
    return s;
}
MatrixIndex Matrix::find(double value)//поиск элемента
{
    int fl=0;
    MatrixIndex s;
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
            if(mass[i][j]==fabs(value))
            {
                s.firstindi=i;
                s.firstindj=j;
                fl=1;
            }
    if(fl==0)
        throw Badvalue();
    //if(rows()==1)//дан столбец
    //  return s.firstindj;
    //else
    //  if(cols()==1)//дана строка
    //      return s.firstindi;
    //  else throw Badindex(); 
    return s;

}
Matrix Matrix::onematrix(int n)//единичная матрица
{ 
    Matrix s(n,n);
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
            mass[i][j]=1;
    return s;
}
Matrix Matrix::zeromatrix(int n)//нулевая матрица
{
    Matrix s(n,n);
    for(int i=firsteli;i<kolrow+firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=firstelj;j<kolcol+firstelj;j++)
            mass[i][j]=0;
    return s;
}
double Matrix::operator () (const int &i,const int &j)//возвратит ссылку на элемент
{
    if (i<firsteli ||i>=kolrow||j<0||j>=kolcol||j<firstelj)
        throw Badindex();
    return mass[i][j];
}
Matrix Matrix:: copy ()//создает копию матрицы с выделением собственной памяти
{
    /*Matrix x(*this);
mass=new double* [x.kolrow];
    for(int j=0;j<x.kolcol;j++)
    {
        mass[j]= new double [x.kolcol];
    }
    memcpy(mass,x.mass,x.kolcol*x.kolrow *sizeof(double));
    kolrow=x.kolrow;
    kolcol=x.kolcol;
    firsteli=x.firsteli;
    firstelj=x.firstelj;
    submatrix=0;
    return x;*/
    if(submatrix)//если подматрица
    {
        Matrix s(kolrow,kolcol);
        for(int i=s.firsteli;i<s.kolrow;i++)
            for(int j=s.firstelj;j<s.kolcol;j++)
                s.mass[i][j]=mass[firsteli+i][firstelj+j];
        return s;
    }
    else return Matrix(*this);
}
istream & operator>>(istream &is,Matrix  &x)
{
    char c;
    for(int i=x.firsteli;i<x.kolrow+x.firsteli;i++)
        for(int j=x.firstelj;j<x.kolcol+x.firstelj;j++)
            is>>x.mass[i][j];//a
    return is;
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, Matrix &x)
{
    for(int i=x.firsteli;i<x.kolrow+x.firsteli;i++)
    {
        for(int j=x.firstelj;j<x.kolcol+x.firstelj;j++)
            os<<x.mass[i][j]<<'('<<i<<','<<j<<')'<<' ';//a(i,j)_

        os<<'\n';//переход на новую строку

    }
    return os;
}
int main()
{
    //freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    int n=0,i=0,k=0,j=0;
    cin>>n;
  Matrix a(n,n+1);
  cin>>a;
  cout<<a;
  /*Matrix b(n,n+1);
  cin>>b;
  cout<<b;
  cout<<(a+b);
  cout<<a;*/
  //a.sub(i,i+1,a.rows()-i,1);
  //cout<<a;
 /* cout<<a.sub(i+1,i+1,2,2);
  cout<<a.row(i);
  cout<<a.col(i);*/
   // Метод Гаусса решения системы линейных уранений
  for(i=0;i<a.rows();i++)
  { double u,v;
      Matrix c(a.sub(i,i,a.rows()-i,1));
        u=c.max(); // найти номер максимального
    v=c.min(); // элемента по модулю в столбце
        if(fabs(v)>fabs(u)) u=v;
        k=c.find(u).firstindi+i;
       cout<<k;
    if(k!=i)  // поменять местами строки
    {
      Matrix t(1,a.cols());
      t=a.row(k);
      a.row(k)=a.row(i);
      a.row(i)=t;

    }
    cout<<'\n'<<a;
   // a.row(i)/=a(i,i); // ведущий элемент привести к 1
   // for(j=0;j<a.rows();j++) // вычесть i-строку из всех других
   //   if(j!=i)              // строк
   //   {
   //     a.row(j)-=a.row(i)*a(j,i);
   //   }
  }
  // в последней колонке получаем решение уравнения
  cout<<a.col(n);
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Почти полтыщи строк кода и невнятный вопрос -- это круто!

Comment: Будьте добры, уберите **весь** код, который не нужен в рамках вопроса. Проблема не в методе Гаусса, а в изменении подматрицы? Так сконструируйте пример, который **только** это и воспроизведёт. И выкиньте закомментированный код, он-то уж точно никому не интересен.

Если ваш пример длиннее 50 строк, вряд ли многие захотят с ним разбираться.

Comment: После globali и globalj перестал читать

Comment: Опять матрица - это указатель на указатель:
`public: double **mass;`
Да еще и в `public` :(